# How to change title/label menu in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Can i change the title/label menu in django admin?
let say i wanna change "POLLS" to "MASTER" and "QUESTIONS" to "ALL QUESTIONS"?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can rename Choices and Questions with adding that to models:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "ALL QUESTIONS"
```

Comment: thanks sir, and now can i change POLLS to MASTER?

Comment: i found it, just adding verbose_name = "" in app.py :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override this on Admin class and not the Model class, you can do so by overriding the default in init.

```py
class QuestionsAdmin(models.Admin):
    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super().__init__(model, admin_site)
        self.opts.verbose_name_plural="all questions"
```